# How to convert dates to date format and sort data by date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a bar graph, however the X-axis dates are out of order with my current code. I know I have to make the to_*char to to*_date but am unsure how to since I also need the date as a char as well for the bind variable.

```
select project_name, Dates, sum(records_number) as 
from (
select project_name, 
  case 
    when :P33_Date_Range = 'Monthly' then
      to_char(date_sys, 'Month') 
    when :P33_Date_Range = 'Daily' then
      to_char(date_sys, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') 
    when :P33_Date_Range = 'Weekly' then
      to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
  end as Dates, date_sys, records_number
from BATCH
WHERE date_sys BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2022') AND TO_DATE('01/01/2023')
) my_records
group by project_name, Dates
order by project_name, Dates
;
```

I know I have to make the to_*char to to*_date but am unsure how to since I also need the date as a char as well for the bind variable.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate the dates to the appropriate range in the sub-query and then use that to order by and format the date in the outer query after aggregation:

```sql
SELECT project_name,
       TO_CHAR(date_sys, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') AS dates,
       SUM(records_number) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT project_name, 
         CASE :P33_Date_Range
         WHEN 'Monthly'
         THEN TRUNC(date_sys, 'MM') 
         WHEN 'Daily'
         THEN TRUNC(date_sys, 'DD') 
         WHEN 'Weekly'
         THEN TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW')
         END AS date_sys,
         records_number
  FROM   BATCH
  WHERE  date_sys >= DATE '2022-01-01'
  AND    date_sys <  DATE '2023-01-01'
)
GROUP BY project_name, date_sys
ORDER BY project_name, date_sys;
```

If you want the month formatting to be different then:

```sql
SELECT project_name,
       TO_CHAR(
         date_sys,
         CASE :P33_Date_Range
         WHEN 'Monthly'
         THEN 'Month'
         ELSE 'DD-Mon-YYYY'
         END
       ) AS dates,
       SUM(records_number) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT project_name, 
         CASE :P33_Date_Range
         WHEN 'Monthly'
         THEN TRUNC(date_sys, 'MM') 
         WHEN 'Daily'
         THEN TRUNC(date_sys, 'DD') 
         WHEN 'Weekly'
         THEN TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW')
         END AS date_sys,
         records_number
  FROM   BATCH
  WHERE  date_sys >= DATE '2022-01-01'
  AND    date_sys <  DATE '2023-01-01'
)
GROUP BY project_name, date_sys
ORDER BY project_name, date_sys;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GomnVJKY)

Comment: Thanks for your help, this orders the dates by day but not month. So my order is 01-Feb, 02-Jan, 03-Sept

Comment: @SannaNaveed Then use a different alias for the formatted date string to the unformatted date and order by date not the string.